# Make CSS text with mix-blend-mode: difference opaque black/white only

Tags: css, mix-blend-mode

I'm trying to apply an effect to a text on a website, where, depending on the text position on the screen, the font color changes. You can see that the text is divided in black and white, and whem I change the browser window size, the white and black areas increases or decreases, depending on the location of the background - in this case, a black div and an picture.

This should be the final result:
[image]

But I'm getting this:
[image]

As you can see, where the font meets the white background, the colour changes to black, which is fine, but when the font crosses the lady image, the font becomes kinda transparent, showing the image behind. In this case, even when the font cross with a background image, the font should still be black.

This effect I achieved this using the mix-blend-mode on CSS, but I can't find a solution for when the text meets the background image.

Would you guys have any other solution or an idea on how I could improve this?
I couldn't find anything online.

Here is the component code:

```
import { NavLink } from "react-router-dom";
import arrowRight from "./../../../assets/icon-arrow-right.svg";
import heroImg from "./../../../assets/desktop/image-hero@2x.jpg";

export function HomeTop() {
  return (
    <section className={style.homeTopContainer}>
      <h1>
        Modern <br /> Art Gallery
      </h1>
        <div className={style.blackBg}></div>
        <img
          src={heroImg}
          alt="a man and a woman standing in front of a paint hanging on a white wall"
          className={style.heroImg}
        />
      <div className={style.topTextBtn}>
        <p>
          The arts in the collection of the Modern Art Gallery all started from
          a spark of inspiration. Will these pieces inspire you? Visit us and
          find out.
        </p>
        <NavLink
          to="/location"
          style={{ textDecoration: "none" }}
          className={style.locationBtn}
        >
          <button className={style.btn1}>Our Location</button>
          <button className={style.btn2}>
            <img src={arrowRight} alt="arrow right icon" />
          </button>
        </NavLink>
      </div>
    </section>
  );
}
```

Here is the CSS applied to the H1:

```
.homeTopContainer h1 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 284px;
  left: 14.4%;
  top: 20%;
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 9.6rem;
  color: var(--color4-white);
  line-height: 8.8rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  white-space: nowrap;
  mix-blend-mode:difference;
}
```

This is the website, in case you want to check it: [Modern Art Gallery](https://modern-art-gallery-tm.netlify.app).

This is a similar situation if you want to play with the code: https://jsfiddle.net/4nwbprg8/

Comment: You'll need to share a playground or some way we can reproduce the problem. Ask yourself, given *only* the code in this post, am I able to recreate my problem? (the answer is currently no). If we can't reproduce the problem, it becomes incredibly difficult or impossible to help.

Comment: @vera It is required to post a [mcve] here, **within the question**, and [not a link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254430/162698) to any other site.

Comment: @Rob Yes that's what I meant by the second sentence in my comment. Playground links are supplements but are appreciated.

Comment: hey @vera. , you can find a similar situation on this link if you want to play a bit. Many thanks for the heads up! https://jsfiddle.net/4nwbprg8/

Answer (score 1):

I doubt that it is possible to achieve what you want by using mix-blend-mode: difference. It works differently, because it encounters background colors and it calculates them too and then you get the result of colors. You could try with this instead "//codepen.io/ashraftoobler/pen/VeoVPL"

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using mix-blend-mode, you can use 2 divs side by side and ident the text

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  font-size: 60px;
  font-weight: 900;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

span {
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.left, .right {
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.left {
  background: black;
  color: white;
  text-indent: 50%;
}

.right {
  background-image: url(https://modern-art-gallery-tm.netlify.app/static/media/image-hero@2x.99a2cfc8e59d8e44df05.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position-y: 50%;
  text-indent: -50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left">
    <span>modern</span>
    <span>art gallery</span>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <span>modern</span>
    <span>art gallery</span>
  </div>
</div>
```